# flutter webrtc Group call not working in android ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-webrtc

I have used the Flutter Webrtc package for video/audio calling but I am not getting the desired outcome in group calls. If there are multiple users like 3+ the call connection not working properly. And I having conflicts and issues with the group calls.

If anyone can help me with this it will be good for me.

Thanks in advance.

I Have tried to follow the steps which are already mentioned in doc. But not getting the desired outcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.